# gridview is disappearing when clicked on rowediting event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am creating a web app in which in my gridview i have a row RowEditing event in which i am assigning the value of label into my textbox in EditItemTemplate

but i was facing the problem,

my textbox was appearing on the second click,for example

> I need to click twice then my textbox was appearing and (suppose i
>   click on row number(1) and the on row number(5) the textbox was
>   appearing on row number(1))

this was how my code look

```
protected void gridone_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    Label lblone = (Label)gridone.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("lbltaskmid");
    string one = lblone.Text;
    string script = "alert('" + one + "');";
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script, true);
}
```

so i change the code like this

```
protected void gridone_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    Label lblone = (Label)gridone.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("lbltaskmid");
    string one = lblone.Text;
    string script = "alert('" + one + "');";
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script, true);
    gridone.DataBind();
}
```

and now my gridview is disappearing when i click on the edit button

here is my html code of gridview

```
<asp:GridView OnRowEditing="gridone_RowEditing" ID="gridone" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbltaskmid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("taskmid") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txttaskmid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbltaskname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("taskname") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txttaskname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbldesc" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("description") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtdesc" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Edit" HeaderText="Add" ShowHeader="True" Text="EDIT" />
    </Columns>    
</asp:GridView>
```

what i need to do here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `EditIndex` of the GridView.

```
protected void gridone_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gridone.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

    gridone.DataSource = mySource;
    gridone.DataBind();
}
```

And `FindControl("lbltaskmid")` will not work since `lbltaskmid` is not in an  EditItemTemplate. Better do FindControl and read/write controls in the RowDataBound event.